# Lag and stutter when pressing keys or moving the mouse

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-iv

So, I have all the recommended specs for GTA IV:

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit
- AMD FX-4100 Quad core at 3.6GHz
- 8GB of RAM
- Radeon HD6450 512MB

More than enough to run the game, but whenever I load it up it will stutter every time I press a button or move the mouse.

Any answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you installed all the latest drivers? what other programs are running in the background? have you tried lowering/changing the graphic-settings? some more information would be really useful...

Comment: If you could post your current game settings, that would help a lot in identifying the issue.

Comment: See the [PC Gaming Wiki - GTA IV](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_IV) article.

Answer (score 1):

Run the game as Administrator.

Also, I had such issue due to the DVD security from GTA.

Answer (score 0):

Since GTA IV is a fairly CPU heavy game, check if it's using all the cores. While the game is running, alt-tab out, then go to Task Manager -> Processes -> GrandTheftAutoIV.exe -> affinity.